# Debug C++ dll from C# works in VS2013, but not VS2010

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Enabled "Enable native code debugging" setting in 2010/2013 and verified debug symbols are loaded.  Cannot step into the C++ source.  After running the same project in VS2013 (without changing any settings), code steps into the C++ source.  Why?

Note: This is being run from a c# unit test project.

Answer (score 0):

Having the PDB file next to the DLL is not enough to debug the DLL.
You will need to have access to the DLL code so that you can step into it from your debugger.
Have a look at that thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69e84750-6636-4656-bbd4-8d3586290af3/how-to-debug-native-c-dll-from-c-application?forum=netfxcompact